# Unable to load Kernel in EMR Studio Notebook with EMR on EKS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-emr, amazon-eks

I've set up an EMR Notebook with EMR on EKS following the steps outlined in the tutorial. (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/ManagementGuide/emr-studio-create-eks-cluster.html )

After creating the workspace, it is able to connect to the virtual cluster however it seems like the Kernel doesn't load for some reason.  After accessing the network tags in the inspector, I notice that a request to this URL https://EDITED/us-west-2.amazonaws.com/HIDDEN/api/kernelspecs?1610647187504

returns {"message": "Error attempting to connect to Gateway server url 'http://localhost:17777 '.  Ensure gateway url is valid and the Gateway instance is running.", "reason": null}.

I'm using release emr-6.2.0-latest

Comment: it seems the gateway server url is actually running on port 9547. idk where this 17777 is coming from

Comment: i was able to get around this issue by launching the managed endpoint into a node group rather than using the fargate profile.